# UnsatisfiedLinkError while building Spinnaker components

Tags: java, jna, spinnaker

I am installing Spinnaker from [source](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker) on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with java-8-oracle installed.
After bringing up redis, C* and configuring $HOME/.spinnaker/spinnaker-local.yml, I ran

> $SPINNAKER_HOME/build/spinnaker/dev/run_dev.sh

as suggested [here](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker#start-spinnaker-services).
All spinnaker component builds are failing as shown below, with the message **"failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted"**.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'rush-core'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > /tmp/jna-dharmi/jna4851962221283619240.tmp: /tmp/jna-dharmi/jna4851962221283619240.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
   > Could not initialize class nebula.plugin.info.ci.POSIXUtil
   > Could not initialize class nebula.plugin.info.ci.POSIXUtil
```

with stacktrace and debug flags, I see the below stacktrace related to JNA on clouddriver.

```
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring root project 'clouddriver'.
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > /tmp/jna-dharmi/jna4716337565952230017.tmp: /tmp/jna-dharmi/jna4716337565952230017.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'clouddriver'.
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:496)
.....
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:55)
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
.....
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-dharmi/jna4716337565952230017.tmp: /tmp/jna-dharmi/jna4716337565952230017.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibraryFromJar(Native.java:752)
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:737)
org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:129)
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at nebula.plugin.info.ci.POSIXUtil.<clinit>(POSIXUtil.groovy:8)
```

'appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Is your system running SELinux?  Does it prevent loading of shared libraries from arbitrary locations?  You might try installing JNA independently so that it's available on the system and not loaded from a temporary installation.

Comment: Thanks @technomage.  SELinux was not setup, but apparmor was enabled by default. passing jna.tmpdir property resolved the issue.

Comment: @Dharmi: How did you enable "stacktrace" option. Where exactly? can you please help.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the tmp location for JNA resolved the issue.

```
-Djna.tmpdir="/some/other/location"
```

reference [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jna-users/OfOYFt8WPwI).